# Android Receiving text in bundle returns Null

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I'm new to Android and Java.  I'm trying to capture values in one activity and pass them to another activity using a bundle.  The bundle is created OK.  But when I try to extract the values in the second activity I get Null values.  What am I doing wrong?
Main Activity

```
//Create the bundle
Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data to bundle
mybundle.putString("One",textOne);
mybundle.putString("Two",textTwo);
//Add the bundle to the intent
myIntent.putExtras(mybundle);
//Fire the second activity
startActivity(startIntent);
```

This is the code for getting the text in the second activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Bundle mybundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String myText1 = mybundle.getString("One");
String myText2 = mybundle.getString("Two");
```

OK.  I will share all my code.  I am trying a very simple program to learn android.  Enter two numbers to add together on the first screen.  Have the answer displayed on a second screen using a bundle to pass the values from the first screen to the second screen.

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText editNum1;
EditText editNum2;
Button addbutton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
editNum1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNum1);
editNum2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNum2);
Button addbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
AddActivity.class);
final String textOne = editNum1.getText().toString().trim();
final String textTwo = editNum2.getText().toString().trim();
//Create the bundle
   Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data to bundle
 mybundle.putString("One",textOne);
 mybundle.putString("Two",textTwo);
//Add the bundle to the intent
 myIntent.putExtras(mybundle);
//Fire the second activity
startActivity(myIntent);
```

OK Now the code for the AddActivity Screen  I've inserted some debugging lines that aren't working either

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Number gNum1;
    Number gNum2;
    Number total;
    String myText1;
    String myText2;
    TextView textView;
    TextView textView2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle mybundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (mybundle != null) {
        String myText1 = mybundle.getString("One");
        String myText2 = mybundle.getString("Two");
    }
    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    if (myText1 != null) {
        textView.setText(myText1);
    }else {
        textView.setText("FAILED");
    }

    textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    if (myText1 != null) {
        textView2.setText(myText1);
    }else{
      textView2.setText("FAILED");
```

Comment: Your code is ok. Maybe textOne or textTwo is null. How you get it?

Comment: can you please put you Intent code here. Because u have sending data with`putExtras(mybundle)` starting intent with `startActivity(startIntent)`.

Comment: You are adding bundle to myIntent and you pass different intent(startIntent) can you please add complete code.

Comment: Please check `startActivity(startIntent);` you are adding bundle to `myIntent` and `startactivity` of `startIntent`.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add bundle in intent who starts the activity.
Please use below code

```
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: I changed that and still getting Null values.  See full revised code above

Answer (score 0):

You are adding bundle to `myIntent` and you passing `Bundle` different `Intent intent(startIntent)`

**use this**

```
//Create the bundle
Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data to bundle
mybundle.putString("One",textOne);
mybundle.putString("Two",textTwo);
//Add the bundle to the intent
startIntent.putExtras(mybundle);
//Fire the second activity
startActivity(startIntent);
```

**insted of this**

```
//Create the bundle
Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();
//Add your data to bundle
mybundle.putString("One",textOne);
mybundle.putString("Two",textTwo);
//Add the bundle to the intent
myIntent.putExtras(mybundle);
//Fire the second activity
startActivity(startIntent);
```

> **NOTE :**
>   if you are getting value from `Textview` or `Editext` than

**use this**

`textOne.getText().toString().trim()`

**insted of this**

```
textOne
```

Comment: I've trimmed the text and made sure I have the right intent name in the startActivity line, but I'm still getting a Null bundle in my second activity.  Let me share all my code

Comment: @Pickles57 you forgot add **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);** in your **AddActivity**

Comment: Thanks Nilesh I added the line "setContentView(R.layout.activity_add)" and the application now runs.  However, the bundle is still returning null values and based on my debugging code in the AddActivity shown above both text view boxes are now saying "FAILED"

Comment: I ran in debugging mode with a break at "String myText1 = mybundle.getString("One");"  It shows me that mybundle !=null In fact it has both values and their keys.  The problem now seems to be extracting the text strings from the bundle.  The line "String myText1 = mybundle.getString("One");" is returning a Null value.

Comment: @Pickles57 try to send  hardcode string via bundle like `mybundle.putString("One","DATA EXAMPLE");`

Answer (score 0):

you are putting bundle in myIntent but you are starting your activity with startIntent that's why you are getting NULL

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity while creating bundle add it to whichever intent you want to start activity.

i.e In the first activity

```
//Create the bundle
Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();

//Add your data to bundle
mybundle.putString("One",textOne);
mybundle.putString("Two",textTwo);

//Add the bundle to the intent
myIntent.putExtras(mybundle);

//Fire the second activity with your bundle added intent
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Then in the second activity make a null check for bundle and then retrieve it

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Bundle mybundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if(mybundle!=null){
    String myText1 = mybundle.getString("One");
    String myText2 = mybundle.getString("Two");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();
mybundle.putString("One",textOne);
mybundle.putString("Two",textTwo);
myIntent.putExtras(mybundle);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

use myIntent instead of startIntent. Since you have added bundle to myIntent you cannot access that bundle Activity which is invoked by another Intent

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the bundle in the myIntent and starting the Activity with startIntent. So use below Code

```
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Now on the other Activity check if the getIntent is not null then fetch the Bundle from the Intent.

Comment: Try using the if(null!=getIntent()) condition for better result. Sometimes nullpointerexception is also resolved by checking the condition in this way.